# Eigen runtime assertion due to fixed size members

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

When running my program I am currently retrieving the following Eigen assertion:

> test_engine: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:128: Eigen::internal::plain_array::plain_array() [with T = double; int Size = 16; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & (31)) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

The exact line of code which causes this assertion is:

```
  std::shared_ptr<Reference> ptr_tmp = std::make_shared<ReferenceLinCart>(cart_traj);
```

where `Reference` and `ReferenceLinCart` are defined in a common header file as:

```
  struct Reference {
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    virtual ~Reference() {}
  }

  struct ReferenceLinCart : Reference {
    Eigen::Transform<double, 3, Eigen::Affine> T_start;
    Eigen::Transform<double, 3, Eigen::Affine> T_goal;
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  };
```

The link in the description provided me with information concerning static size structure members, which is why I added the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` flag.

The g++ compile flags used are:  -march=native -funroll-loops -std=c++11 -Ofast -Wall

Unfortunately I am still retrieving the same runtime assertion. Any suggestion on how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `make_shared` does not honor requested alignement nor use `operator new` for allocation. You need to use [allocate_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) with an aligned allocator (e.g., `Eigen::aligned_Allocator`).

Answer (score 0):

compile the code with c++17, the bug(memory allocator) is fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).